# Pass a value with dropzone

Tags: php, dropzone.js

I am generating an html table using PHP for which each row has a dropzone form element to upload an image with. My problem is that I can't figure out a way to pass a variable along with the dropzone form to my PHP upload page.

e.g.

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    $imagepath = 'dir' . $k . 'jpg';
    $image = file_exists($imagepath) ? 'yes' : '<form action="include/upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>';
    echo "<tr><td>" . $image . "</td></tr>";
```

I read the dropzone docs, and saw the methods used to configure. But that would mean that I'd had to manually configure each row which would take forever. I want to just pass `$k` along to `upload.php` so that it can save the image with the appropriate name.

upload.php:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $imagick = new Imagick(realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
    $imagick->resizeImage(1000,1000,imagick::FILTER_CATROM,1,TRUE);
    $imagick->writeImage(???need image name to write???);
    $imagick->destroy();
}

?>
```

$k is the id of the database entry for that row and I want to name the images $k.jpg. How can I do this?

Comment: what value do you want to pass exactly? a solution can be to create a hidden input for each row in the php

Comment: I tried doing that but it wouldn't take the input value, I'll update my question

Comment: Actually I solved it, I don't really know what the problem was but I could not get the hidden input value to be passed initially. Now I simply added an input `<input type="hidden" name="hidden_value" value="50">` and then in `upload.php` I can access it by `$_POST["hidden_value"]`

Answer (score 0):

You pass it just like any other form element.

replace :

```
<form action="include/upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>
```

with :

```
<form action="include/upload.php" class="dropzone">
   <input type='hidden' name='myParam1' value='put value here'>
   <input type='hidden' name='myParam2' value='put value here'>
</form>
```